# Problem with newlines when I use toprettyxml()

Tags: python, xml

I'm currently using the `toprettyxml()` function of the `xml.dom` module in a Python script and I'm having some trouble with the newlines.
If don't use the `newl` parameter or if I use `toprettyxml(newl='\n')` it displays several newlines instead of only one.

For instance

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(dom1.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8'))
f.close()
```

displayed:

```
<params>


    <param name="Level" value="#LEVEL#"/>


    <param name="Code" value="281"/>


</params>
```

Does anyone know where the problem comes from and how I can use it? 
FYI I'm using Python 2.6.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`toprettyxml()` is quite awful. It is not a matter of Windows and '\r\n'. Trying any string as the `newl`parameter shows that too many lines are being added. Not only that, but other blanks (that may cause you problems when a machine reads the xml) are also added.

Some workarounds available at
http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/xml-dom-minidom-toprettyxml-and-silly-whitespace

Comment: thanks a lot Xv ! Indeed, now, I'm trying to use toprettyxml() as few as possible but it's good to know there is a workaround for this annoying issue. And the post is very clear

Comment: from xml.dom.ext import PrettyPrint
from StringIO import StringIO

def toprettyxml_fixed (node, encoding='utf-8'):
    tmpStream = StringIO()
    PrettyPrint(node, stream=tmpStream, encoding=encoding)
    return tmpStream.getvalue()

Comment: It would be helpful to link the code, in case your website goes down etc.

Comment: xml.dom.ext was not added to Python libstd. It is part of custom distributions, probably to fix this awfulness.

Answer (score 20):

I found another great solution :

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
dom_string = dom1.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')
dom_string = os.linesep.join([s for s in dom_string.splitlines() if s.strip()])
f.write(dom_string)
f.close()
```

Above solution basically removes the unwanted newlines from the dom_string which are generated by toprettyxml().

Inputs taken from -> [What's a quick one-liner to remove empty lines from a python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140958/whats-a-quick-one-liner-to-remove-empty-lines-from-a-python-string)

Comment: For python3, it needs to be ```dom_string = b'\n'.join([s for s in dom_string.splitlines() if s.strip()])```

Comment: This is the only solution I've found that doesn't require a third-party library, nice work.

Comment: this particular code does not work, since excplicit `encoding` argument makes the function to return bytes, not string

Comment: Here it is an updated version that work with Python 3.10 `'\n'.join([s for s in dom_string.decode().splitlines() if s.strip()])` The answer should be edited.

Answer (score 5):

`toprettyxml(newl='')` works for me on Windows.

Comment: Work on Ubuntu 16.04 (bash) too

Comment: This works on every line except the first one, it seems to strip the newline and combine line 1 and 2...

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty old question but I guess I know what the problem is:

Minidoms pretty print has a pretty straight forward method. It just adds the characters that you specified as arguments. That means, it will duplicate the characters if they already exist.

E.g. if you parse an XML file that looks like this:

```
<parent>
   <child>
      Some text
   </child>
</parent>
```

there are already newline characters and indentions within the dom. Those are taken as text nodes by minidom and are still there when you parse it it into a dom object.

If you now proceed to convert the dom object into an XML string, those text nodes will still be there. Meaning new line characters and indent tabs are still remaining. Using pretty print now, will just add *more* new lines and *more* tabs. That's why in this case not using pretty print at all or specifying `newl=''` will result in the wanted output.

However, you generate the dom in your script, the text nodes will not be there, therefore pretty printing with `newl='\r\n'` and/or `addindent='\t'` will turn out quite pretty.

TL;DR Indents and newlines remain from parsing and pretty print just adds more

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind installing new packages, try beautifulsoup. I had very good experiences with its [xml prettyfier](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML).

Answer (score 0):

Following function worked for my problem.
I had to use python 2.7 and i was not allowed to install any 3rd party additional package.

The crux of implementation is as follows:

1. Use dom.toprettyxml()
2. Remove all white spaces
3. Add new lines and tabs as per your requirement.

~

```
import os
import re
import xml.dom.minidom
import sys

class XmlTag:
    opening = 0
    closing = 1
    self_closing = 2
    closing_tag = "</"
    self_closing_tag = "/>"
    opening_tag = "<"

def to_pretty_xml(xml_file_path):
    pretty_xml = ""
    space_or_tab_count = "  " # Add spaces or use \t
    tab_count = 0
    last_tag = -1

    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xml_file_path)

    # get pretty-printed version of input file
    string_xml = dom.toprettyxml(' ', os.linesep)

    # remove version tag
    string_xml = string_xml.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>", '')

    # remove empty lines and spaces
    string_xml = "".join(string_xml.split())

    # move each tag to new line
    string_xml = string_xml.replace('>', '>\n')

    for line in string_xml.split('\n'):
        if line.__contains__(XmlTag.closing_tag):

            # For consecutive closing tags decrease the indentation
            if last_tag == XmlTag.closing:
                tab_count = tab_count - 1

            # Move closing element to next line
            if last_tag == XmlTag.closing or last_tag == XmlTag.self_closing:
                pretty_xml = pretty_xml + '\n' + (space_or_tab_count * tab_count)

            pretty_xml = pretty_xml + line
            last_tag = XmlTag.closing

        elif line.__contains__(XmlTag.self_closing_tag):

            # Print self closing on next line with one indentation from parent node
            pretty_xml = pretty_xml + '\n' + (space_or_tab_count * (tab_count+1)) + line
            last_tag = XmlTag.self_closing

        elif line.__contains__(XmlTag.opening_tag):

            # For consecutive opening tags increase the indentation
            if last_tag == XmlTag.opening:
                tab_count = tab_count + 1

            # Move opening element to next line
            if last_tag == XmlTag.opening or last_tag == XmlTag.closing:
                pretty_xml = pretty_xml + '\n' + (space_or_tab_count * tab_count)

            pretty_xml = pretty_xml + line
            last_tag = XmlTag.opening

    return pretty_xml

pretty_xml = to_pretty_xml("simple.xml")

with open("pretty.xml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(pretty_xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives me nice XML on Python 3.6, haven't tried on Windows:

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)

pretty_xml_as_string = dom.toprettyxml(newl='').replace("\n\n", "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you viewing the resulting file on Windows?  If so, try using `toprettyxml(newl='\r\n')`.