# Specify newline character for cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, newline, celementtree

### Code

I'm writing an xml file with cElementTree like this:

```
cElementTree.ElementTree(xml_tree]).write(xmlPath, encoding="ISO-8859-1", xml_declaration=True)
```

---

### actual result

This gives the following file (on Windows):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><tag1 = "1"></tag1>
```

So the newlines are missing.

I tried adding the appropiate windows newline characters `\r\n` 'by hand', now I get this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><tag1 = "1">
</tag1>
```

---

### desired result

However, I would like to have the correct newline character after each line, so that my output should look this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<tag1 = "1">
</tag1>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The newlines have no meaning.

Comment: Besides the link in @Tichodroma's answer, there is also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python), which has even more (and possibly better) information.

Comment: @Tichodroma: I know that, though I have a tool that cannot read the xml file without newlines. And I cannot change this tool :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) supports pretty printing, `cElementTree` doesn't.

```
from lxml import etree
xml_str = "<parent><child>text</child><child>other text</child></parent>"
root = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

See [Python pretty XML printer for XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973819/python-pretty-xml-printer-for-xml-string) and [Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But lxml is not included in the standard installation of python. As I want to use this on several computers, this is a "no go", unfortunately.