# Python script to generate XML file from PSQL database table

Tags: python, xml, postgresql

I am trying to generate XML file from PostgreSQL database table. I was able to generate using below code but it is not formatted and displaying in single line. While getting row from rows it displays complete file in single row. How can I fix this problem?

```
def tableToXML(message):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='DB' user='user' password='i123456'")
    except:
        print "I am unable to connect to the database."

    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT table_to_xml('usapp_sipconf', true, false, '')")
    except:
        print "I can't SELECT from sipconf"

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    with open('sipconf.xml', 'w') as f:
        for row in rows:
            print row
            f.write("%s" % (str(row)))
    if conn:
        conn.close()
    return True
```

Comment: There's no problem. XML is still valid and well-formed but just doesn't have line breaks or indentation for human readability. Look for Python modules to pretty print output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have generated XML file from PostgreSQL database table by making thses modification to pre-existing code.

```
def tableToXML(tableName):
    conn       = None
    columnList = []
    fileName   = 'usappxml/'+tableName+'.xml'
    message    = '<'+tableName+'>\n'

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='dbuser' password='123456'")
    except:
        print " ***  Can't able to connect database. *** "
        return False

    outfile = file(fileName, 'w')
    cursor  = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '%s'" % tableName)
    columns = cursor.fetchall()

    for column in columns:
        columnList.append(column[0])

    cursor.execute("select * from  %s" % tableName)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    outfile.write('<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n')
    outfile.write(message)
    for row in rows:
        outfile.write('  <row>\n')
        for i in range(len(columnList)):
            outfile.write('    <%s>%s</%s>\n' % (columnList[i], row[i], columnList[i]))
             outfile.write('    <%s>%s</%s>\n' % (columnList[i], row[i], columnList[i]))
        outfile.write('  </row>\n')
     outfile.write(message)

    outfile.close()
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered multiple times:

[Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

[How do I get Python's ElementTree to pretty print to an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813876/how-do-i-get-pythons-elementtree-to-pretty-print-to-an-xml-file)

[Python pretty XML printer for XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973819/python-pretty-xml-printer-for-xml-string)