# Appending and formatting a new SubElement via ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

Using the following code, I can successfully add a subElement where I want, and functionally it works. For readability, I want to format the way `item.append` inserts the new sub elements.
My Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(file.xml)
root = tree.getroot()

for items in root.iter('items'):
    item = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
    item.append((ET.fromstring('<item>cat</item>')))    

tree.write('output.xml')
```

XML File:

```
<interface>
    <object>
        <items>
            <item>dog</Item>
        </items>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Expected output:

```
<interface>
    <object>
        <items>
            <item>dog</item>
            <item>cat</item>
        </items>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Actual output:

```
<interface>
    <object>
        <items>
            <item>dog</item>
            <item><item>cat</item></item></items>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Usually I wouldn't care about how it formats the output.xml file. However, I will be adding `<item>` subElements in a `while` loop, so when I have 4 or 5 additions, the code will get a little sloppy for readability's sake.

I have looked at a lot of similar questions concerning this, but they are either unanswered, or don't apply specifically to what I am trying to do.

Here is my code in the while loop, just incase it will add more clarification:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(file.xml)
root = tree.getroot()

while True:

    item_add = input("Enter item to add: 'n")
    item_string = '<item>'
    item_string += item_add
    item_string += '</item>'

    for items in root.iter('items'):
        item = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
        item.append((ET.fromstring(item_string)))   

tree.write('output.xml')

#Code asking for more input, if none break out of loop
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `.find()` to walk down to your needed node and then simply use `SubElement` to add. No need for string versions of markup when working with DOM libraries like `etree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

while True:
    item_add = input("Enter item to add: ")

    if item_add == 'x':
        break

    items = root.find('object').find('items')
    tmp = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
    tmp.text = item_add

# PRINT TO SCREEN
print(ET.tostring(root).decode('utf-8'))

# SAVE TO FILE
tree.write('output.xml')
```

**Output** *(after entering cat, frog, zebra in inputs, use x to end loop)*

```
<interface>
    <object>
        <items>
            <item>dog</item>
        <item>cat</item><item>frog</item><item>zebra</item></items>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Use built-in `mini.dom` or third-party `lxml` for [pretty printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973819/python-pretty-xml-printer-for-xml-string).