# Python toprettyxml() formatting problems

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to process XML using Python's minidom, and then output the result using toprettyxml().  I ran into two problems:

1. There are added blank lines.
2. There are added newlines and tabs for text nodes.

Here's the code and output:

```
$ cat test.py
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parse("test.xml")
print dom.toprettyxml()

$ cat test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<store>
    <product>
        <fruit>orange</fruit>
    </product>
</store>


$ python test.py
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<store>


    <product>


        <fruit>
            orange
        </fruit>


    </product>


</store>
```

I can workaround problem 1 using strip() to remove blank lines, and I can workaround problem 2 using the hack (fixed_writexml) described in this link: http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/xml-dom-minidom-toprettyxml-and-silly-whitespace/, but I was wondering if there's a better solution since the hack is almost 3 years old now.  I'm open to using something other than minidom, but I'd like to avoid adding external packages like lxml.

Comment: You may check-out my solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39984422/2687547

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty lines while using minidom.toprettyxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479656/empty-lines-while-using-minidom-toprettyxml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to patch minidom Library with the [proposed patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue1777134) to the bug you mention.

I haven't tested myself, a bit hacky too, so it may not suit you!

Comment: Thanks, I tested the patch, and it fixes both issues!  Instead of directly patching minidom.py in /usr/lib/python, I did something similar to the ronrothman link above, where the function is replaced at runtime.  That way, it can run anywhere.

Comment: Hey, could you please share your solution to the patch ? thanks !