# Merge multiple XML files from command line

Tags: xml, command-line, merge

I have several xml files. They all have the same structure, but were splitted due to file size. So, let's say I have `A.xml`, `B.xml`, `C.xml` and `D.xml` and want to combine/merge them to `combined.xml`, using a command line tool.

A.xml

```
<products>
    <product id="1234"></product>
    ...
</products>
```

B.xml

```
<products>
  <product id="5678"></product>
  ...
</products>
```

etc.

Comment: try adding the tag xmlstarlet to increase the number of people looking at your question. Also tag for OS, windows, unix/linux, or ??  Good luck.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80609/merge-xml-documents

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### xml_grep

http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep

> **xml_grep** --pretty_print indented --wrap products --descr '' --cond
>   "product" *.xml > combined.xml

- --wrap : encloses/wraps the the xml result with the given tag. (here: `products`)
- --cond : the xml subtree to grep (here: `product`)

Answer (score 23):

High-tech answer:

Save this Python script as `xmlcombine.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def run(files):
    first = None
    for filename in files:
        data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
        if first is None:
            first = data
        else:
            first.extend(data)
    if first is not None:
        print(ElementTree.tostring(first))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(sys.argv[1:])
```

To combine files, run:

```bash
python xmlcombine.py ?.xml > combined.xml
```

For further enhancement, consider using:

- `chmod +x xmlcombine.py`:
  Allows you to omit `python` in the command line
- `xmlcombine.py !(combined).xml > combined.xml`:
  Collects all XML files except the output, but requires bash's `extglob` option
- `xmlcombine.py *.xml | sponge combined.xml`:
  Collects everything in `combined.xml` as well, but requires the `sponge` program
- `import lxml.etree as ElementTree`:
  Uses a potentially faster XML parser

Comment: In MacOS Python 2.6 ... I'm getting `_ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'extend'`. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: This was probably Python 2.7 on Linux.  You could work around that by iterating over the children and adding each one manually; or perhaps lxml will work for you.

Comment: on trying i am getting 
 ./xmlcombine.py ?.xml > combine.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xmlcombine.py", line 17, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./xmlcombine.py", line 8, in run
    data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 579, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '?.xml'

Comment: @Vik: The question mark is a shell globbing character, standing for any single character.  If your xml files aren't named like the ones in the question, then ?.xml fails to match anything, so the shell passes it as-is to the program, which complains because there's no file with that name.  Try passing it the real names of your files; just make sure that the output file doesn't get passed in as an input.

Comment: @eswald i am getting the error: "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document elemente: line 89, column 0", what should I do?

Comment: @InêsMartins: That means one of your source xml files isn't correctly formatted.  First, ensure that your output file isn't getting listed as one of the input files by mistake; if that's not the issue, then check the format of each input file.  Try running xmlcombine.py on each file individually, and see which one produces the error.

Comment: This just concatenates both input files within a single top level element. It does not merge on a lower level. So, I get something like `<foo><bars><bar1/><bar2/></bars><bars><bar3/><bar4/></bars></foo>`. It does not merge the lower levels as in `<foo><bars><bar1/><bar2/><bar3/><bar4/></bars></foo>`

Comment: For pretty printing change it like this: https://i.imgur.com/s10GEBp.png (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984422/6907424)

Answer (score 2):

Low-tech simple answer:

```
echo '<products>' > combined.xml
grep -vh '</\?products>\|<?xml' *.xml >> combined.xml
echo '</products>' >> combined.xml
```

Limitations:

- The opening and closing tags need to be on their own line.
- The files need to all have the same outer tags.
- The outer tags must not have attributes.
- The files must not have inner tags that match the outer tags.
- Any current contents of `combined.xml` will be wiped out instead of getting included.

Each of these limitations can be worked around, but not all of them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Merging 2 trees includes the task to identify what is identical and what should be replaced. Unfortunately, this is not obvious. There is more semantic involved than what can be inferred from the source XML documents.

Consider the case where the first document has a middle level with several elements having the same tag, but different attributes. The second document adds an attribute to that middle level to an existing element, but also another child to it. One has to know the semantic.

```
<params>
...
<param><name>hello</name><value>world</value></param>
...
</params>
```

add/merge:

```
<params>
   <param><name>hello</name><value>yellow submarine</value></param>
</params>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very helpful tool is [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), which aims to be `jq` for YAML, TOML and XML.

It can be installed via pip, the xml handling command is then called `xq`.

```bash
pip install yq
xq .products ?.xml --xml-output --xml-root=products > combined.xml
```