# Merging XML elements while keeping the contents using python

Tags: python, xml

I've been looing around for a method to remove an element from an XML document,while keeping the contents, using Python, but i haven't been able to find an answer that works.

Basically, i received an XML document in the following format (example):

```
<root>
    <element1>
        <element2>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element2>
    </element1>
    <element1>
        <element3>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element3>
    </element1>
</root>
```

What i have to do is to merge element2 and element3 into element1 such that the output XML document looks like:

```
<root>
    <element1>
        <element2>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element2>
        <element3>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element3>
    </element1>
</root>
```

I would appreciate some tips on my (hopefully) simple problem.

Note: I am somewhat new to Python as well, so bear with me.

Comment: Do you want to _remove_ `element1`, or do you want to _merge_ them?

Comment: Merge them, my bad. Edited the main post as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921642/merging-xml-files-using-pythons-elementtree

Comment: First you need to find all between <text></text> tags. Append to array all elements with those values. Then you can create your new XML file.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the prettiest of solutions, but since there's no other answer yet...

You could just search for, e.g., `</element1><element1>` and replace it with the empty string.

```
xml = """<root>
    <element1>
        <element2>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element2>
    </element1>
    <element1>
        <element3>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element3>
    </element1>
</root>"""

import re
print re.sub(r"\s*</element1>\s*<element1>", "", xml)
```

Or more generally, `re.sub(r"\s*</([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)>\s*<\1>", "", xml)` to merge all consecutive instances of the same element, by matching the first element name as a group and then looking for that same group with `\1`.

Output, in both cases:

```
<root>
    <element1>
        <element2>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element2>
        <element3>
            <text> random text </text>
        </element3>
    </element1>
</root>
```

For more complex documents, you might want to use one of [Python's many XML libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml) instead.

Comment: This should work until i find a better way using an XML library. Thank you very much.