# Merging multiple xml files with different attributes into one attribute

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to merge multiple xml files into one. I have come across multiple previously answered similar solutions. However, I have not found one that fits my problem. I have 3 xml files with different attributes. One of the xml files has a `<main1></main>`.I am trying to grab the content of the other xml files and place it inside this tag along with the existing data.

test1.xml

```
<acura>
    <Brand>Acura</Brand>
    <Model>NSX 2017</Model>
    <Price>156000</Price>
</acura>
```

file2.xml

```
<honda>
    <Brand>Honda</Brand>
    <Model>Accord</Model>
    <Price>24</Price>
</honda>
```

something3.xml

```
<main>
<bmw>
    <Brand>BMW</Brand>
    <Model>5 Series</Model>
    <Price>51200</Price>
</bwm>
</main>
```

Comment: Do you have already any code or do you want to someone write it for you? If you have, pls show it, otherwise I am not sure that anyone would write a code. If it is not required to use elementtree, I have similar code, which I can adopt to your needs.

Comment: The data in files(cars) always are different? Is possible duplicates?

Comment: @TitanFighter I been trying to work of this code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921642/merging-xml-files-using-pythons-elementtree) but no luck

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Sorry, I updated the tags accordingly

Comment: @MaryCoding first of all your `xml` doesn't have [declaration](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml). The second, if in `test1` and in `file2` can be many cars then you should wrap it in any `tag`(for example `cars` or `items` etc.). One more thing: you have mistake in tag `</bwm>`(is not `</bmw>`)

Comment: @MaryCoding add please some source what are you tried.

Comment: There are no attributes in any of these XML files, only elements and their values.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you might need to know about is `insert`.

Parse each of the files and then, use `Brand` to navigate to the car's marque as parent or grandparent. Finally `insert`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('c:/scratch')
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> test1 = etree.parse('test1.xml')
>>> file2 = etree.parse('file2.xml')
>>> something3 = etree.parse('something3.xml')
>>> acura = test1.find('Brand').getparent()
>>> acura
<Element acura at 0xa27388>
>>> honda = file2.find('Brand').getparent()
>>> main = something3.xpath('.//Brand')[0].getparent().getparent()
>>> main.insert(0, acura)
>>> main.insert(0, honda)
>>> str = etree.tostring(main, pretty_print=True)
>>> str
b'<main>\n<honda>\n    <Brand>Honda</Brand>\n    <Model>Accord</Model>\n    <Price>24</Price>\n</honda><acura>\n    <Brand>Acura</Brand>\n    <Model>NSX 2017</Model>\n    <Price>156000</Price>\n</acura><bmw>\n    <Brand>BMW</Brand>\n    <Model>5 Series</Model>\n    <Price>51200</Price>\n</bmw>\n</main>\n'
```