# Merge xml files with nested elements with attributes and values

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878706/merge-xml-files-with-nested-elements-without-external-libraries/58500809#58500809) solution I have an issue.

Merging xml-files.

My problem is, that I have to consider the values also.

And the duplicates has to be removed.

In this excample the entries with FileB.txt are duplicated.

FileA.xml

```
<update>
  <Files>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileA.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileA.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileB.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileB.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </Files>
</update>
```

FileB.xml

```
<update>
  <Files>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileB.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileB.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileC.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileC.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </Files>
</update>
```

expected Result.xml

```
<update>
  <Files>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileA.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileA.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileB.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileB.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileC.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileC.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </Files>
</update>
```

If I change the mapping to

```
    mapping = {(el.tag, hashabledict(el.attrib), el.text): el for el in one}
```

the parent element CopyFile is missing.

My result will be

```
<update>
  <Files>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileA.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileA.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileB.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileB.txt</DestFile>
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileC.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileC.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </Files>
</update>
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml1 = '''<update>
  <Files>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileA.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileA.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileB.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileB.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </Files>
</update>'''
xml2 = '''<update>
  <Files>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileC.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileC.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </Files>
</update>'''


root1 = ET.fromstring(xml1)
root2 = ET.fromstring(xml2)
copy_files = [e for e in root1.findall('.//CopyFile')]
src_files = set([e.find('./SrcFile').text for e in copy_files])
copy_files.extend([e for e in root2.findall('.//CopyFile') if e.find('./SrcFile').text not in src_files])

merged_root = ET.Element('update')
files = ET.SubElement(merged_root, 'files')
files.extend(copy_files)

ET.dump(merged_root)
```

output

```
<update><files><CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileA.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileA.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
    <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileB.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileB.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  <CopyFile overwrite="FALSE">
      <SrcFile>\FolderA\FileC.txt</SrcFile>
      <DestFile>\FolderB\FileC.txt</DestFile>
    </CopyFile>
  </files></update>
```

Comment: this will not remove dublicates

Comment: Please define "duplicate"

Comment: the entries with FileB.txt are duplicates in the sourcefiles.

Comment: What is the element that the code should look at: `SrcFile` or `Destfile` in order to check for duplicats?

Comment: the SrcFile is the identifier to detect duplicate

Comment: @mswyss Duplicates are handled now.