# How to remove empty lines with or without whitespace

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I have large string which I split by newlines.
How can I remove all lines that are empty, (whitespace only)?

pseudo code:

```
for stuff in largestring:
   remove stuff that is blank
```

Comment: [For myself, I found the answer here is the best solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140958/whats-a-quick-one-liner-to-remove-empty-lines-from-a-python-string#answer-24172715)

Comment: One liner to remove empty lines (without whitespace) is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1140966/2373278) .  Question headline could potentially be changed to 'Remove empty lines with whitespace only in python'.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using regex:

```
if re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
    # line is empty (has only the following: \t\n\r and whitespace)
```

Using regex + [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'^\s*$', x), original)
```

As seen on [codepad](http://codepad.org/YRZBjjpB).

Comment: Thanks for all the results, however, this solution was exactly what I had been looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: gimel's solution, with re-joining the text afterwards, gives a far better performance. I compared the two solutions on a small text (10 lines if which 3 were blank). Here are the results:
regex: `1000 loops, best of 3: 452 us per loop`; 
join, split & strip: `100000 loops, best of 3: 5.41 us per loop`

Comment: Introductory video: [Python Tutorial: re Module - How to Write and Match Regular Expressions (Regex) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8L6KVGG-7o)

Answer (score 72):

Try list comprehension and [`string.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> mystr = "L1\nL2\n\nL3\nL4\n  \n\nL5"
>>> mystr.split('\n')
['L1', 'L2', '', 'L3', 'L4', '  ', '', 'L5']
>>> [line for line in mystr.split('\n') if line.strip()]
['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5']
```

Comment: you can shorten it by omitting the  != ''  simply "if line.strip()"

Answer (score 27):

I also tried regexp and list solutions, and **list one is faster**.

Here is my solution (by previous answers):

```
text = "\n".join([ll.rstrip() for ll in original_text.splitlines() if ll.strip()])
```

Answer (score 14):

```
lines = bigstring.split('\n')
lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()]
```

Comment: That would work for lines = ['Line\n', '\n', 'Line\n'] but the input is 'Line\n\nLine\n' .

Comment: @Walter: Actually, if you used 'Line\n\nLine\n'.split() like you should have, it would work just fine.

Comment: Works for me with `bigstring.split('\n')`

Comment: This isn't at all what OP asks for.  Try it with "a b c": it returns "a\nb\nc".

Answer (score 9):

Surprised a multiline re.sub has not been suggested (Oh, because you've already split your string... But why?):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "Foo\n \nBar\nBaz\n\n   Garply\n  \n"
>>> print a
Foo

Bar
Baz

        Garply


>>> print(re.sub(r'\n\s*\n','\n',a,re.MULTILINE))
Foo
Bar
Baz
        Garply

>>>
```

Comment: On a multiline sub, \s* will match any number of \n and any other whitespace:
> >>> import re
> >>> a = "foo\n \n\t\n \nbar\n\n \n baz"
> >>> print(re.sub(r'\n\s*\n','\n',a,re.MULTILINE))
> foo
> bar
>   baz

grumble.  I apparently can't figure out markdown in comments.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not willing to try regex (which you should), you can use this:

```
s.replace('\n\n','\n')
```

Repeat this several times to make sure there is no blank line left. Or chaining the commands:

```
s.replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\n\n','\n')
```

<sub>Just to encourage you to use regex, here are two introductory videos that I find intuitive:

• [Regular Expressions (Regex) Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA)

• [Python Tutorial: re Module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8L6KVGG-7o)</sub>

Comment: You may want to use a regular expression, for example. "Repeat several lines to be sure" is not a good idea when you are coding, as you may leave things unsolved or waste time running something more times than needed.

Comment: +1 to regex, but as a lazy hack (or if importing the regex module is too slow) you can chain replace statements: 
`s.replace('\n\n','\n').replace('\n\n','\n')`
Tested on 3.6.

Comment: @evan_b didn't think of chaining commands. Which one will be executed first?

Comment: Execution order appears to be left to right, but I wasn't able to find that documented anywhere after searching briefly, so it may not be safe to rely on that for order-sensitive replacements.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use rstrip:

```
    for stuff in largestring:
        print(stuff.rstrip("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution to delete empty lines and join everything together as one line:

```
match_p = re.sub(r'\s{2}', '', my_txt) # my_txt is text above
```

Answer (score 1):

Use positive lookbehind regex:

```py
re.sub(r'(?<=\n)\s+', '', s, re.MULTILINE)
```

When you input:

```
foo
<tab> <tab>

bar
```

The output will be:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: This doesn't work on first line of the file :(

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
while '' in all_lines:
    all_lines.pop(all_lines.index(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_whith_space = """
    example line 1

    example line 2
    example line 3

    example line 4"""

new_str = '\n'.join(el.strip() for el in str_whith_space.split('\n') if el.strip())
print(new_str)
```

Output:

```
""" <br>
example line 1 <br>
example line 2 <br>
example line 3 <br>
example line 4 <br>
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `map` and `strip` to remove spaces and use `filter(None, iterable)` to remove empty elements:

```
string = "a\n \n\nb"
list_of_str = string.split("\n")
list_of_str = filter(None, map(str.strip, list_of_str))
list(list_of_str)
```

Returns: `['a', 'b']`

Answer (score -1):

Same as what @NullUserException said, this is how I write it:

```
removedWhitespce = re.sub(r'^\s*$', '', line)
```