# How do I remove the empty line from this file?

Tags: python

I have this file called `foo.txt` and it has the following content:

```
# [empty line here]
bar 12
baz 34
```

the empty line is caused by removing everything in that line, here is the code:

```
newdict = {}
with open('foo.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.isalpha() == True: 
            splitline = line.split( )
            newdict[(splitline[0])] = ",".join(splitline[1:])
removethis = raw_input("Item to be removed: ")
if removethis in newdict:
    with open('foo.txt','r') as f:
        f.read()
    new = new.replace(removethis, '')
    with open('foo.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(new)
    with open('foo.txt','rw') as g:
        for line in g:
            if not line.isspace():
                g.write(line)
```

I want to remove the empty line from the file but nothing happens.

EDIT: To someone who marked this as duplicate, no thanks I don't want regex

Comment: do `new.replace('\n\n', '\n')`

Comment: You have to close the file!!! f.close()

Comment: @wonka I thought "with as" automatically closes it

Comment: @user7091717 you're right.

Comment: It does automatically close, and what exactly do you want to do? I'm still a bit unclear. Do you just want to know how to remove empty lines from a file?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of `f.read()` inside the `if` statement?

Comment: @silverslash yes, but not manually since I'd want to do it right after I remove something. When I remove something it leaves a gap, an empty line where it used to be in. After removal, I wanted to immediately edit the text file so that it would not have any empty space in it.

Comment: @SilverSlash I first need to read everything before I could make modifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty lines with or without whitespace in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711856/how-to-remove-empty-lines-with-or-without-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: Where is `new` first declared?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open('data/aa', 'rw') as f, open('data/aa2', 'w') as f2:
    newf = [a for a in f if a.strip()]
    f2.writelines(newf)
```

---

Or you can do it with sed as well (if you are on linux):

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' foo.txt
```

Comment: could you please explain what sed and '/^\s*$/d' mean?

Comment: @user7091717 Are you on linux?

Comment: what does the `if a.strip()` do? doesn't it need to have some condition

Comment: and, doesn't .strip() also remove the spaces and line separation?

Comment: When you do `a.strip()` you will get empty string for lines containing only whitespaces. Empty string is considered as false and those lines will be skipped. `.strip()` removes whitespaces in a string on both the ends of string.