# Remove all blank lines from a text file in python

Tags: python, txt

I'm trying to figure out how to remove an empty line from a text file while only using python.
The input should be like:

```
firstline
secondline

thirdline
```

And the output should be:

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
```

So I have this right now...

```
import sys

with open("New Text Document.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.isspace():
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: It's not "do it for me' board friend.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see (how to ask a good question)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Your code already gives your desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove empty lines with or without whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711856/how-to-remove-empty-lines-with-or-without-whitespace-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('demo.txt', 'r')
arr = file.readlines()
print([v for v in arr if not v.isspace()])
```