# Remove line breaks from txt file

Tags: python

If I want to remove line breaks from a text file such as this:

```
hello

there
```

and I use a simple code like this:

```
with open('words.txt') as text:
  for line in text:
    print (line.strip())
```

It outputs this:

```
hello

there
```

However, I want my code to output this:

```
hello
there
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered testing whether or not the `line` is empty?

Comment: for removing empty text lines you may try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140958/whats-a-quick-one-liner-to-remove-empty-lines-from-a-python-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `if line.strip() == '': continue` before your `print` statement.

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways to achieve what you want.

1. Reading line by line

   ```
   with open('bla.txt') as stream:
       for line in stream:
           # Empty lines will be ignored
           if line.strip():
               print(line)
   ```
2. Reading all contents

   ```
   import re
   with open('bla.txt') as stream:
       contents = stream.read()
       print re.sub('\s$', '', contents, flags=re.MULTILINE)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if its only linebreaks you want to remove, you could use `string.replace("\n", "")`

or if it only uses carraige returns instead of newlines (*nix) then `string.replace("\r", "")`

James

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if a line is empty or not to solve this.

```
with open('words.txt') as text:
    for line in text:
        if line:
            print (line.strip())
```

In python empty-strings are falsy. That is, an if-test on an empty string will be considered false.